# Ubuntu power management taskbar widget disappeared

Tags: ubuntu, taskbar, power

The power status dropdown widget in ubuntu 9.04 disappeared. I'm referring to the one in the corner which (when pidgin is installed) displays user status, and has a dropdown to shut down, suspend, hibernate, etc. The system menu still contains commands to do this, but I'd prefer to use the dropdown in the corner.

How can I get it back?

Edit: The fix was to reset the panels with this command:

```
gconftool-2 --shutdown && rm -rf ~/.gconf/apps/panel && pkill gnome-panel
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is the little battery icon, it is kept in the 'Notification area'.
Right-click the upper panel, select 'Add to Panel' and then add 'Notification area'.

Edit:
As a last resort you could try reseting the panels completely as shown in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/7225/how-do-i-restore-a-panel-in-ubuntu).

Comment: I tried adding a notification area, and it added an empty widget to the panel. I can see the handle, but there doesn't seem to be anything IN the thing I added. Any idea why?

Comment: Strange... If I add a second notification area, it does what you describe in your comment but if I then delete the 'live' one the icons jump to the previously empty one :¬/  
???

Comment: Sweet! The reset command from that other thread did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Right click on menu bar. Click on Add to panel and add whichever buttons you need

Comment: None of the items in that list seem to be the widget I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

The thing you want to add is the "battery charge monitor" right at the top of the list. Keep in mind though that it can be set to **not** display itself when the laptop isn't running on battery power.

Comment: My battery charge monitor is perfectly visible. This is the login/logout dropdown menu.